# MQ Error in Load Runner Reason code 2009

Tags: performance-testing, ibm-mq, loadrunner

We are trying to run one test which send message to MQ. When running this from Vugen its working fine and message can be seen in queue but when running from Performance centre with same script and identical setting. Its showing below error.
Can someone help me with this.

```
 Error: System.err: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009 MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect Closure reason = 2009 Error
```

Comment: You would need to have the MQ admin look at the queue manager logs to tell you the reason for the connection broken error.

Comment: It would seem clear that a dependency which is installed on your VUGEN development host is not installed on the Load Generator.  Consider remote desktoping to the remote generator and running your script locally in VUGEN for greater details.

It would also be helpful to understand what protocol you are using for this connection: Java, WinSock, MQTester, other....